# Quick check regarding C# namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces

Okay, there's `System` and `System.Web`.  Am I correct in that the structure this suggests is:

```
namespace System
{
    // all of the outer namespace members

    namespace Web
    {
        // all of the inner members
    }
}
```

And that when a namespace is nested within another, having a `using` directive with the parent/outer namespace *only* doesn't automatically bring in the child/nested namespace?  In other words:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        context1 = new HttpContext(); // won't work

        context2 = new System.Web.HttpContext(); // will work
    }
}
```

Just trying to see if I actually understand this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* nest namespaces and any `using` directive would only grant access to the members defined within the specific namespace you are referencing.

So from your example:

```
namespace System
{
    // all of the outer namespace members

    namespace Web
    {
        // all of the inner members
    }
}
```

Referencing `System` would grant you access to the outer namespace members and referencing `System.Web` would grant you access to all of the inner namespace members.

But this is atypical and usually namespaces are defined only once within a file.  The dot-notation typically follows a folder or project structure, so files that were nested as such:

```
WebApplication
    - Models
        - MyModel.cs
    - Controllers
        - MyController.cs
```

Might use namespaces of `WebApplication.Models` and `WebApplication.Controllers`.

I can't think of a great example off the top of my head where you would want to nest namespaces, but there may be a good reason to.  However, it would be considered an exception to the rule, in my opinion.

Comment: Chosen as answer for the dot notation clarification.

Comment: I don't think namespaces have anything to do with "referencing" or "access", but that's just me.

Answer (score 3):

System.Web is declared as:

```
namespace System.Web
{
    public class HttpContext {}
}
```

However, it would be possible to actually declare a child namespace:

```
namespace System
{
    namespace Web
    {
        public class HttpContext {}
    }
}
```

I have never seen something like this but the syntax allows it and the effect is the same. In both cases, the namespace of `HttpContext` is `System.Web.HttpContext`.

Even with the second example, `using System;` wouldn't import the child namespace, only the *types* defined in that namespace are imported.

Comment: Ah, so it's a standalone namespace?

Comment: I don't think that really makes any difference.

Comment: @KevinM1: In that case yes. But it really doesn't make a difference, please see my extended answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a using directive only allows types declared in that namespace to be used without namespace qualifier. Nested namespaces are not automatically included.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel said, `System.Web` is not declared separately. `System` and `System.Web` are two separate namespaces which are technically unrelated.

That's why your code example of `new HttpContext()` won't work - because `HttpContext` is not in the `System` namespace at all.

Answer (score 1):

this is a common confusion regarding composite namespaces. Heres a great article of microsoft about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx